# How to use RtlDecompressBuffer without knowing the size of the uncompressed data?

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to use the WINAPI RtlDecompressBuffer in User Mode to decompress a buffer previously compressed using RtlCompressBuffer. I have the code for compression but it seems that in order to decompress I need to know the size of the uncompressed data as the function needs it as a parameter.

How can I do this without knowing the size of the uncompressed data?
Perhaps I should use RtlDecompressFragment.

A code sample would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know the size of the uncompressed data. All you have to do is reserve enough memory to hold all the uncompressed data and pass that to the API.
If your buffer isn't big enough, the API will return `STATUS_BAD_COMPRESSION_BUFFER` and you then have to allocate a bigger buffer for the uncompressed data.

Comment: Thanks, this will do, although not perfect.

Comment: Hi, apparently, this is not quite correct. It seems that sometimes the function will return STATUS_SUCCESS even if there is still data left to be decompressed. The only solution I have found is to preallocate 13 times more than the compressed buffer which is based on the assumption that you cant compress anything by more than 92%.

Answer (score 3):

Why not adding (while compressing) a simple header (first 4 bytes) to the buffer with the uncompressed size?